# Dynamically change View Stub layout_height attribute?

Tags: android, layout, view, viewstub

I am using **view stub** in my application. I am inflating the **view stub** to the layout and it is working fine. Now if you see the **dummy_layout.xml** there I have given the **android:layout_height=20dp**. What I need to do is to **change that view stub height from 20 dp to Wrap_Content** on a button click. How can I achieve this?

My ultimate goal is this. I have a button in it. when i click on it for first time I need to show the full layout of stub. and again when I click on it for the second time I need to animate the stub to slide down and show only a part of it.

**dummy_layout.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_watch_pic" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/viewStub1"
        android:layout="@layout/stub_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        **android:layout_height="20dp"**
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my class:

```
public class DummyFragment extends Fragment {

    private View mRootView;
    private Context mContext;
    private Button mButton;
    private boolean isVisible = true;
    private RelativeLayout mParentLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_layout,
                container, false);

        mContext = getActivity();

        mButton = (Button) mTopLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.viewStub1);

            **final View inflated = stub.inflate();**

        inflated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final View viewstublayout = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.viewStub1);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isVisible)
                {
                    isVisible=false;    
                    inflated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    isVisible=true;                     
                    inflated.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        return mRootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: IMO, the ViewStub is flawed as it should literally "become" the view that's newly inflated within it.  Including any params, width, height, gravity, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width/height of a view by editing its [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). Example:

```
View stub = findViewById(R.id.viewStub1);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = stub.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
stub.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The better question is why you want to do this? Maybe there's a better way of achieving your goal.

Comment: I have a button in it. when i click on it for first time I need to show the full layout of stub. and again when I click on it for the second time I need to animate the stub to slide down and show only a part of it.

Comment: This should work then. Don't know a better/cleaner way on the top of my head but then again I haven't used expandable views before. If you're stuck, let me know :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    final ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.viewStub1);
    View view = stub .inflate();
```

inside button click

```
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if works well.

```
LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) (YourView).getLayoutParams();

 lp.height = newheight;
 YourView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```